Java Module workaround of duplicate packages?
For a project of mine I wanted to include a Library.
However I also have a dependency on another Program which also includes said Library, but not fully but only a section of it, as the full Library is 27MB.
Now when I am trying to run my program it will result in a crash which I assume is caused by a duplicate package which java doesn't like.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module Primitive.Collections contains package speiger.src.collections.chars.maps.impl.hash, module speiger.src.collections exports package speiger.src.collections.chars.maps.impl.hash to Primitive.Collections
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolveFail(Resolver.java:901)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.failTwoSuppliers(Resolver.java:815)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.checkExportSuppliers(Resolver.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.finish(Resolver.java:380)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:140)
    at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:494)

My question now, is there some sort of solution/workaround for this?
